# Show Custom Post Type taxonomy term that matches custom field

Tags: custom-post-types, php, custom-taxonomy, custom-field

Not sure how well I can explain this but I will try. I have two Custom Post Types. One is "Locations" and one is "Members." I need to show only the members that belong to the location. "Locations" has an Advanced Custom Field of 'city' that would match "Members" taxonomy of 'location.' So, I want to know how I can only show posts if a term matches a field.
Here is my WP_Query for "Members" that displays all "Members" separated by 'location' terms:

```
<?php $loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'member', 'posts_per_page' => -1 ) ); ?>
<?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); $do_not_duplicate = $post->ID; ?>
    <?php the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail'); ?>
    <div class="caption">
        <h4><?php the_title(); ?></h4>
        <h5>
            <?php
                $term_names = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'location', array ( 'fields' => 'names' ) );
                echo wp_sprintf_l( '%l', $term_names );
            ?>
        </h5>
    </div>
<?php endwhile; wp_reset_query(); wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

I also have this:

```
<?php $city = get_field('city'); ?>
```

So, what I'm asking is how do get only the posts with taxonomy 'location' term that matches '$city' to display?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be easy enough. First, get the City.

```
<?php $city = get_field('city'); ?>
```

Then in your WP_Query, insert the taxonomy parameter:

```
<?php $loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'member', 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'location' => $city ) ); ?>
```

Et Vilola: you only get the Members that have the taxonomy $city.